# VBA: Autofilter with dropdown on multiple entrie cell

Tags: vba, excel

I want to filter on Column which includes cells with multiple input e.g.:

**Column: B**

B2: Banana / Apple
B3: Banana
B4: Apple / Cherry
B5: Banana/ Cherry / Apple
B6: Cherry / Banana / Coconut

By using my macro on Filtering "Banana" from a dropdown, only B3 will be shown, but i want to have all the others as well wehere Banana is listed: B2, B3, etc.

**My code looks like this:**

```
Sub Choose_Fruit()
'
'
   Dim Kriterium As String 
   Range("F20").Select 
   Kriterium = ActiveCell.Value 

    '
   Sheets("Fruits").Select
   ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table9").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Kriterium
End Sub
```

Any Idea what I did wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having an `*` as a wildcard is the way to go, indeed. However, you can write it either in the `Kriterium` itself, or pass it in the `Criteteria1` string, making it a bit more robust.

The biggest problem with your code is that you are working too much with `Select`, `ActiveCell`, `Activate`, etc. This is how to avoid these:

```
Sub ChooseFruit()

   Dim Kriterium As String
   Kriterium = Worksheets("SomeSheet").Range("F20")
   WorkSheets("Fruits").ListObjects("Table9").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, _
                            Criteria1:="*" & Kriterium & "*"

End Sub
```

Comment: And adding a sheet reference to F20 as I'm assuming it's on a different sheet.

Comment: @SJR - yup, with sheet reference it looks a bit better.

Answer (score 1):

Use `*` as wildcard character to search for "Banana" in every cell.

Change

```
Kriterium = ActiveCell.Value
```

to

```
Kriterium = "*" & ActiveCell.Value & "*"
```

Comment: In such scenarios, whenever you are in doubt, record a macro ;)